# Parse military time to double in flutter

Tags: flutter, parsing, time, double

I am trying to convert a textfield input of military time into a double. Can anyone help me with this? goal would be if someone enters 13:45 then the output would be 13.75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide your input into 2 halves around the `:`. Then parse each half, which results in separate hours and minutes `int`s. Add them together, dividing the minutes by 60 to get your intended `double` output.

```
String input = "13:45";
  
String firstHalf = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(':'));
String secHalf = input.substring(input.indexOf(':') + 1);
  
int hour = int.parse(firstHalf);
int min = int.parse(secHalf);
  
double output = hour + min/60;
print(output);//13.75
```